# Llamar a un stored procedure que devuelve un dato

Tags: sql, python-3.x

Tengo un `stored procedure` que devuelve un dato:

```
ALTER proc sp_foo(@id int, @name nvarchar(256), @str_conn  nvarchar(256), @sql nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    insert into foo_table(id, name, str_conn, [sql]) values (@id, @name, @str_conn, @sql)

    select @@identity foo_table_id
end
```

Cuando lo llamo desde python:

```
def connection():
    return pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cnn = connection()
cursor = cnn.cursor()

parametros = (ID,NAME,STR_CONN,SQL)

query = """EXEC sp_foo @id = %s, @name = '%s', @str_conn = '%s', @sql = '%s'"""%parametros
try:
    cursor.execute(query)

    cursor.commit()
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
except Exception as e:
    print('*'*100)
    print(e)
cnn.close()
```

Me arroja la excepción :

> No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

También intenté con `sqlalchemy` y tampoco tuve éxito:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

output:

> ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has
>   been closed automatically.

Sí comento la linea  de `fetchall()`, hace el insert, pero no me muestra el dato que devuelve el procedimiento almacenado.

Esa misma `query` que se genera en python, la pego en el `sql` y se ejecuta perfectamente y me devuelve el valor:

```
 1 record(s) affected 

 foo_table_id
 --------------------------- 
 62
```

Comment: Hola Lucas, ¿has probado con `cursor.fetchval()` en vez de `cursor.fetchall()`?

Comment: Mañana a primera hora lo probaré, espero que sea eso, más alla de eso, hay algún problema en usar la palabra reservada `sql` y `name` ?, No es mio el sp, pero me hace un poco de ruido que use las palabras reservadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que pude encontrar fue modificar el `Stored Procedure` agregandole [SET NOCOUNT ON](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Esto lo que hace es eliminar el mensaje de salida de *n record(s) affected*.

Entonces el `Stored Procedure` tendría esta forma:

```
ALTER proc sp_foo(@id int, @name nvarchar(256), @str_conn  nvarchar(256), @sql nvarchar(max))
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    insert into foo_table(id, name, str_conn, [sql]) values (@id, @name, @str_conn, @sql)

    select @@identity foo_table_id
    SET NOCOUNT OFF
end
```

Y como devuelve un solo registro puedo usar `fetchval()` o `fetchval()`. Tener en cuenta que `fetchall()` por más que devuelva un registro, va a retornar una lista.